# Jest or React Testing Library failed to render Material UI ToggleButton after using array.map , before using array.map it works, why?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui

Testing codes:

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "../App";

test("The 2nd button is rendered", () => {
  render(<App />);
  expect(screen.getByRole("button", { name: "2ND" })).toBeTruthy();
});
```

My codes (not working version, because I used array.map() to display each ToggleButton, if I don't use array.map(), just display the ToggleButton one by one, then the tests works. The problem is if I use array.map, the testing code cannot render those ToggleButtons at all, why this happened? How can I solve the problem? I want to use array.map() because the code is neat.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ToggleButton, ToggleButtonGroup } from "@mui/material";

const Controller = (props) => {
  const [item, setItem] = useState("first");

  const handleChange = (event, newItem) => {
    setItem(newItem);
  };

  const dataOfAll = props.allData;
  const buttonTextKeyArray = dataOfAll ? Object.keys(dataOfAll) : [];

  const buttonTexts = {
    first: "1ST",
    second: "2ND",
    ot: "OT",
    fullgame: "Full Game",
  };

  function clickHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const keyOfObject = e.target.id;
    const singleRoundAllData = dataOfAll[keyOfObject];
    const singleRoundEventData = singleRoundAllData[3].events;
    props.onGetData(singleRoundAllData, singleRoundEventData);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <ToggleButtonGroup
        color="primary"
        value={item}
        exclusive
        onChange={handleChange}
        aria-label="Platform"
        onClick={clickHandler}
        sx={{ borderRadius: 3, width: "80%" }}
      >
        {buttonTextKeyArray.map((buttonTextKey) => {
          return (
            <ToggleButton
              variant="text"
              id={buttonTextKey}
              key={buttonTextKey}
              value={buttonTextKey}
              className="btn"
              sx={{
                border: "none",
                flexGrow: 1,
                color: "white",
                fontFamily: "Work Sans",
                textTransform: "none",
              }}
            >
              {buttonTexts[buttonTextKey]}
            </ToggleButton>
          );
        })}
      </ToggleButtonGroup>
    </>
  );
};

export default Controller;
```

Comment: Actually, the application works in both ways, meaning with array.map() and without array.map(), both works.

Answer (score 0):

I know now, it is not about material UI. It is because the testing tests the first render of the page, and at that time, data wasn't fetched from backend yet, therefore, by using array.map(), nothing can be displayed. However, if I don't use array.map(), the UI will have the toggle button in the very beginning.